# Flutter: Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm using `Flutter-web` and I want to export a pdf. I'm using the [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package and i'm trying to implement a simple example from their documentation. To be more specific, I have a file called `export_pdf.dart` and the code inside it is the following.

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
import 'package:universal_io/io.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

exportPdf() async {
  final pdf = Document();

  pdf.addPage(Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (Context context) {
        return Center(
          child: Text("Hello World"),
        ); // Center
      })); // Page

  final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final file = File("${output.path}/example.pdf");
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
}
```

When i'm calling the `exportPdf()` function by clicking a button, i'm getting the following error.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation
> found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

I've been searching for this issue for a long time, but no solution has fixed this one.

Even though the `path_provider` package is imported, the `getTemporaryDirectory()` is never called, like it doesn't exist.

I need also to mention that i'm using `universal_io`, instead of `dart:io`, because i'm using `flutter_web`.

This error shows up for every function i'm calling and exists inside the `path_provider/path_provider.dart` file. I've also added inside `path_provider/path_provider.dart` a simple print function and i'm getting an error that the method is not found.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this current package does not support file saving in web and it is suggested to use the printing plugin to print or share the file.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Make sure after the first command, the `build` folder is removed.

Comment: I ran `flutter clean`, build folder did indeed got removed, then i ran `flutter pub get` and lastly `flutter run`. The same error still pops though.